# why do i need $timeout for a location change in this case?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
angular.module('DemoApp')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
      $rootScope.user = null;
      $location.path("/login");
    };
  }]);
```

The problem is that when logout is called, the location does not change. However the following code works (notice the use of $timeout):

```
angular.module('DemoApp')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
      $rootScope.user = null;
      $timeout(function() {
        $location.path("/login");
      });
    };
  }]);
```

Can somebody tell my why this is?

edit:
The HTML looks like this and is inside the NavbarCtrl controller element:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><br/>Abmelden</a>
```

Comment: $timeout with no delay is using as a hack it triggers the $digest loop

Comment: ^ agree. I would try triggering the digest cycle with a $scope.$apply() after your $location.path("/login") call.

Comment: scope apply results in an exception saying that digest is already in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that was wrong is the HTML: `href="#"` causes a location change that somehow cannot be changed again by `$location.path()`. Changing the HTML to `href=""` removes the necessity to use `$timeout`